# Using Microsoft.bcl.async in PCL with Mono Droid?

Tags: xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I have a Portable Class Library (PCL) targeted at Profile158 (Windows Store, .NET 4.5, Silverlight 5, Windows Phone 8). I can easily work with methods that return a type of Task, and it all works as I would expect. Whenever I access the Result property, it finishes running the asynchronous code and returns the result.

However, if I use the async/await keywords in a method inside the PCL, I get a task back. However, when I attempt to access the Result property, it blocks and never returns.

Looking at the debug output window in Visual Studio in both cases I see the same text:

```
Thread started: 
Thread started: 
Loaded assembly: Mono.Security.dll [External]
Thread started: 
Thread started:
```

So it appears as if the code is being run, but it never returns to the UI thread. Has anyone else tried to use a PCL with Microsoft.bcl.async in the PCL?

My Mono Droid project is targeted at Android 2.1.

Thanks,
  -- John

**Update:**
Here is some additional information about the different scenarios. First, here is code that does work on Mono Droid when written in the UI code:

```
var task = request.GetResponseAsync();
string html = task.Result.GetResponseText();
```

I then created the following method in the PCL:

```
public async Task<string> Test()
{
    IHttpResponse responce = await GetResponseAsync();
    return responce.GetResponseText();
}
```

And call it with this code from the Mono UI code:

```
string html = request.Test().Result;
```

it never returns...

Comment: If you use the Result property, that will block until the task completes. If you're doing that from the same thread where the task itself needs to execute, you've basically given yourself a deadlock. It's not at all clear what your code does at the moment... do you have a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @dsplaisted used this layer with MonoDroid during his demo at BUILD - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-004 - I'll add the PCL tag to this post and put out a bat signal - he'll be along during Redmond hours...

Comment: Not related to your question, but Microsoft.Bcl.Async is still beta. Using it in any production code should be avoided. Of course, you might just be testing it right now.

Comment: I am not a lawyer so read the license and decide for yourself, however I believe that the license for Microsoft.Bcl.Async would allow you to use it in production (I think you'd call it a "go live" license).  It's up to you to decide whether the risk is worth it.  However, it actually is *not* licensed for non-Windows platforms.  So you could compile your portable library against it but when it actually runs on Android you would need a different implementation.  In my BUILD demo I did this by adapting the AsyncBridge code.

Comment: shouldn't you use profile 104 not 158??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [classic deadlock scenario](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I describe on my blog.

By default, `await` will capture a "context" and use it to resume the `async` method. This "context" is the current `SynchronizationContext` unless it is `null`, in which case it's the current `TaskScheduler`.

So, you're calling an `async` method from a UI thread (which provides a `SynchronizationContext`), then blocking the UI thread by calling `Result`. The `async` method cannot finish because it is trying to finish on the UI thread, which is blocked.

To fix this, follow these guidelines:

1. Use `async` all the way down. Don't call `Result` or `Wait` on `Task`s returned from `async` methods; use `await` instead.
2. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` whenever possible in your library code.

You may also find my [`async`/`await` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: I'm OK with the UI code blocking until the operation completes. The problem is that it never finishes and never returns to the UI thread. If I return a Task<T> from my method and don't use async/await, the UI code blocks briefly, and then returns.

I've tried the same exact UI code with Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store app, and they both return correctly to the UI thread. I also checked to ensure that SynchronizationContext isn't null in Android, and it isn't. So there is something about Android and PCLs that use async/await that seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: This same deadlock exists in all UIs, including WP8 and netcore. If you have code that uses `Result` on an `async` method in WP8 without deadlock and the same *exact* code deadlocks in Android, then please post the code.

Comment: Are you saying that `Test` code works without deadlock on WP8 and Windows Store? I would certainly expect a deadlock, for the reasons given in my answer and blog post.

Comment: My mistake. I took a another look at my WP8 code and it's using async and await, which is why it's not blocking. So your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: To clarify my answer, *either* of the guidelines would prevent the deadlock, but they're *both* recommended.